# Set-builder notation with complex numbers

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

I'm given the set of complex numbers

$$K_r := \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid (\Re(z)-1)^2 + (\Im(z))^2 = r^2 \} \quad \text{for}  \quad r>0$$

How can I rewrite this set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write $z=a+bi$, then the equation becomes $$(a-1)^2+b^2=r^2$$ which is an equation of a circle centered at $(1,0)$ and with a radius of $r$.

So, the same set can be written as

$$\{z\in\mathbb C; \|z-1\|=r\}$$

---

You can reach the same representation another way. By realizing that $\Im(z)=\Im(z-1)$ and $\Re(z)-1=\Re(z-1)$, you can rewrite it as

$$\{z\in\mathbb C; \Re(z-1)^2 + \Im(z-1)^2=r^2\}$$

now using the fact that $$\|w\|^2=\Re(w)^2+\Im(w)^2$$ gives the same result.

Comment: @philmcole Why would $\|z-1\|=r$ in any way mean $z=r^2+1$?!

Comment: @philmcole What kind of thing could be in the $\ldots$ part of $z=\ldots$ that would give you "an idea of what's happening" and let you plot the set? In particular, what do you imagine we could tell you that would be a clearer idea and more easily plotted than "a circle centered at $(1,0)$ with a radius of $r$"?

Comment: It seems that you have a question you want answered, and rather than ask that question, you have made a guess at a different question you can ask that you think will get you to the answer you need. Sometimes this works, but often it doesn't. I suggest you edit your question to say what you expect to do with this formula for $z$ once you get it; and exactly what formulas or other objects have you been given that describe this "inverse function" and "image set" you're interested in? It might be worth copying out the original problem that led you to this question.

Comment: @philmcole That's not really fair to change the answer like that. You posed a question, and I answered it. What you should then do is ask a **new** follow-up question, rather than change this one.